# Storing and Accessing nested REST API Urls

Tags: c#, api, rest, data-structures

I am working with a REST API, and I want to be able to efficiently store and access nested URL strings.

My ideal would be to be able to type something like `myHttpClient.PostAsync(url.things.search, mycontent)` and have that execute at runtime as `myHttpClient.PostAsync("myurl.com/thethingsiwant/searchingthethings", mycontent)`, or type `myHttpClient.PostAsync(url.things.create, mycontent)` and resolve it as `myHttpClient.PostAsync("myurl.com/thethingsiwant/creatingathing", mycontent)`, with there being multiple levels and branches of strings listed.

I looked at potentially using a dictionary, but that doesn't give me the clean access to the "." operator that I want and doesn't nest as cleanly either. Enums were likewise unsuitable for my needs, from what I read.

I realize I can create a custom class that will do what I want, but I feel like there should be some data structure that can do what I want more easily, and I just can't quite figure out the right terms to google to find it.

What would be the best way for me to go about making this nested structure of strings?

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried Resource files ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/work-with-resx-files-programmatically

Comment: This is certainly not REST. It's not nesting either. Each URL is doing what the HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT) actually do. To *retrieve* a resource use GET. To create a new one use POST.

Comment: My apologies for not articulating it clearly- It is not REST in itself, but what I am attempting to do is interact with a REST Api, and work with URLs efficiently, and I thought this to be a topic people working with REST Apis would likely have come up against before.

Comment: I don't really get the issue? Why not just create a class/struct and store the URL into strings? But this just smells like something you want from Python that is just terrible and like Python should never be used. Make a proper service and inject it into your DI.

Comment: You're going to need some nested static classes with static properties.

Comment: It's sounding like creating classes is the proper way to go about this, and I appreciate the feedback provided. Resource files look like a bit too heavy of a cleaver for what I'm trying to slice, but I will definitely look into them, as they seem eminently useful for other projects. Thank you, everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking, but you might try creating an instance of HttpClientFactory (assuming you are on .NET Core 2 or later) with a base url.

In Startup.cs, you'd add:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    . . .
    services.AddHttpClient("url.things", c =>
    {
        c.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://myurl.com/thethingsiwant");
    });
    . . .
}
```

Then you'd inject this into your class:

```
private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

public MyService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
{
    _clientFactory = clientFactory;
}
```

And you'd call it this way:

```
var myHttpClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient("url.things");
myHttpClient.PostAsync("creatingathing", mycontent);
```

I *believe* this would work with `PostAsync`, but I'm not 100% sure.  I normally use `SendAsync` and create an `HttpRequestMessage`, so results may vary.

Comment: This doesn't precisely give me the functionality I want, but creating several httpclients with different baseurls and then just adding the last segment is perfectly workable, so I'm accepting it as a sufficient answer.  Thank you!